# Printing the DLLs imported by a PE (64 bit)

Tags: c, winapi, portable-executable

I seriously can't understand why this is happening. I'm able to correctly parse the majory of the PE format except for this. I'm trying to print all DLLs being used by a particular PE.

First I get the ImportTable from the Data Directory:

```
IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY importDir = (IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY)peHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
```

Then I just add its address to the address where I mapped it,i.e the address returned by MapViewOfFile:

```
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR importDescriptor =
        (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((ULONG *)pe + importDir.VirtualAddress);

    printf("%s\n", (ULONGLONG *)pe + importDescriptor[0].Name);
```

For some reason this is crashing, how do I go about this?

Comment: @RemyLebeau did you mean this? `importDescriptor =
  (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((PBYTE)pe + importDir.VirtualAddress);` because this still crashes

Comment: See the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pointer arithmetic is wrong.  `(ULONG *)pe + ...` and `(ULONGLONG *)pe + ...` don't do what you think they do.

When you advance a pointer `T*` by an integer `N`, the address stored in the pointer is advanced by `N` number of `T` *elements* - ie by `N * sizeof(T)` number of *bytes*.

When you type-cast `pe` to `ULONG*` and then add `importDir.VirtualAddress` to it, you are advancing the address stored in `pe` by `sizeof(ULONG) * VirtualAddress` number of bytes, rather than by `VirtualAddress` number of bytes.

Likewise, when you type-cast `pe` to `ULONGLONG*` and then add `importDescriptor[0].Name` to it, you are advancing the address in `pe` by `sizeof(ULONGLONG) * Name` number of bytes, rather than by `Name` number of bytes.

That is not what you want in this situation.  Virtual addresses in a PE are absolute offsets from the base address, so you need to advance the base address by `N` bytes, not multiples of `N` bytes, so any `T*` used for such a type-cast needs to be a pointer to a 1-byte data type, such as `BYTE` or `char`.

So, in your example, to advance your base address `pe` by `N` number of *bytes*, use `BYTE*` for the type cast, eg:

```
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR importDescriptor =
        (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(((LPBYTE)pe) + importDir.VirtualAddress);
...
printf("%s\n", (char*)(((LPBYTE)pe) + importDescriptor[0].Name));
```

Alternatively, you can use integer arithmetic instead of pointer arithmetic, by type-casting your base address to an integer such as `ULONG_PTR` (a pointer-sized `ULONG`), eg:

```
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR importDescriptor =
        (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)(((ULONG_PTR)pe) + importDir.VirtualAddress);
...
printf("%s\n", (char*)(((ULONG_PTR)pe) + importDescriptor[0].Name));
```

Comment: Ok you cleared up my misunderstanding about typecasting, I appreciate it, but I swear to you, this is not working for some reason, I have tested with more than one file. A simplification: https://pastebin.com/67QqqLiL

Comment: Then you are doing something else wrong. We are not here to debug your code for you. Is there a reason why you are not using things like [`ImageDirectoryEntryToData()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-imagedirectoryentrytodata)? Let it handle this low-level parsing for you.

Comment: well, I wanted to do it on my just to get a better understanding of the PE format, there's not much to this code other than what I showed it's literally just supposed to print those strings, but you are probably right anyway

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate.  See the code in the linked questions. Accessing the `DataDirectory` is different between a 32bit and 64bit DLL, so that may be what you are hitting up against

Comment: thanks, the problem was that I had to convert the RVA to a file offset

Comment: What is `pe` ? I guess the imagebase of the exe in memory?